# Remote Debugging x86 project on x86 device with x64 dev machine (VS 2005)

Tags: .net, x86, 64-bit, device, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug a .NET 2 windows forms application on a remote device (Windows CE) via a USB cable and using visual studio 2005.  The remote device is x86 and my dev machine is x64, it seems to work fine on co-workers dev machines, but that are all running x86.

The project builds but will not start, vs gives me the below error.

"The 32-bit version of Visual Studio cannot debug 64-bit processes or 64-bit dumps.  Please remote debug with the 64-bit version of Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) instead."

I have the platform target set to x86 and build configuration will only let me set 'Any CPU' (there are no other options).  Although I did try manually hacking the .csproj file but this didn't work either.

I have been searching the net all morning trying to find a solution, how can I get this to work?

Thanks.